# two post head dependents

Tags: modifiers

> an opinion that someone offers you about what you should do or how you should act in a particular situation ([dictionary.cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/advice))

(1) an opinion 
(2) that someone offers you __ 
(3) about what you should do or how you should act in a particular situation

This noun phrase is not easy to understand. Does the dependent of (3) modify a component of (2), *that*? ; or modify the head of (1), *an opinion*?

Comment: "What is it?" "It's an opinion." "Where do I get it from?" "Someone offers it to you. It's an opinion that someone offers you." "What is it about?" "It's about what you should do or how you should act in a particular situation. It's an opinion that someone offers you about what you should do or how you should act in a particular situation."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can start with this sentence:

> Someone offers you **an opinion** [about what you should do or how you should act in a particular situation].

It should be clear here that the *about*-phrase is attached to **an opinion**.  Let's relativize **an opinion**, turning the whole thing into a noun phrase:

> **an opinion** [*that* someone offers you ___ ] [about what you should do or how you should act in a particular situation]

The *about*-phrase (3) modifies the head noun **an opinion** (1) and would make sense even if you removed the relative *that*-clause (2):

> **an opinion** [about what you should do or how you should act in a particular situation]

This should make the relationship clear.